# Update an Application on GooglePlayStore and erasing persistant data

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

I am curently working on an android application. I have to do a new release and I changed a lot of things, database included.

And it seems the database isn't correctly updated during the update of the application after the release.

So I would like to know if it's possible to force to uninstall the old version of the application to install the update with google play.
I know there is a lot of post out there about this, but apparently everyone want to keep the data they had before the update, and I want the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider this option.

In your **SQLiteHelper**, you can indicate the version of your database.

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Whenever you are making a new release (increasing version number),

- You can add your code to recreate your tables using the **onUpgrade()** function.
- Drop your existing tables if they exist and create the new ones that you define.

Have fun programming!